# How do I set line spacing for FormFields in iText?

Tags: pdf-generation, itext7

It seems like the default line spacing in iText 7 form fields is 2 or 1.5, but I'd really like to remove the line spacing. Normally, I set line spacing by calling `setMultipliedLeading(..)` on a `Paragraph` object, but neither `PdfAcroForm` nor it's subclass, `PdfTextFormField` has this method, and only Strings can be set as the form field value. How do I set the value for line spacing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per ISO-32000-1 12.7.4.3, you are not able to set leading in an AcroForm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did a little reading in the document, and it seems like I might be able to use an appearance stream. Do you know if appearance streams can be used to set the spacing between lines?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know! Worth exploring!

Comment: also, @lucasvw, I _would_ appreciate you selecting my answer as the correct answer :)